# Finding an isomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $R_U$ be the group of units of R. Show that
>
> (i)
>   $\mathbb{C}_U \cong \left(\left(\mathbb{R},+\right)/\mathbb{Z}\right)\times\left(\mathbb{R},+\right)$
>
> (ii)
>   $(\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2-x))_U \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

where $\cong$ stands for *isomorphic as groups*.

(i)

I thought about using the polar form of complex numbers. At first I had a problem with the fact that (for using with the angle) the real numbers can be negative. So I tried the Euler identity to the rescue: $e^{i\pi} = -1$. So if I map $\gamma : (r,\phi) \mapsto r e^{i\pi(1+\phi)}$, this seemed to work. But what about the zero? How can I get this to be injective?

(ii)

First as $\# \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 = 4$, the target group will have 4 elements. But what are they?

I tried $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2-x) = \{ax + b\ \big\vert\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ (right?).

$(ax+b)(cx+d) = 1$ didn't lead me to a useful solution.

Can you please help me to go on?

Comment: The invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2-x)$ are easy to find: they are $\pm1$ and $\pm(2x-1)$.

Comment: @user26857 can you please tell me what exactly you did to get to this result?

Comment: $4x(x-1)=(2x-1)^2-1$, and $x(x-1)=0$ in the quotient ring.

Comment: @user26857 I thought about your answer over and over again. I do understand why those equations apply, but how do they lead to the answer? And how did you get to $4x(x-1)$?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly confuses you? (If you look at CRT can see how the isomorphism is defined. In our case the invertibles are $(\pm1,\pm1)$. Two of these, $(1,1)$, resp. $(-1,-1)$ correspond to $1$ and $-1$ in the factor ring. Now let's consider $(-1,1)$: this comes from a polynomial of degree one (the elements of $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-x)$ are residue classes of such polynomials) $ax+b$ such that for $x=1$ (or modulo $x-1$ if you prefer) we get $-1$ and for $x=0$ (or modulo $x$) we get $1$, so $b=1$ and $a=2$, that is, $2x+1$.)

Comment: "why those equations apply, but how do they lead to the answer?": in the factor ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-x)$ we have $\bar x^2-\bar x=0$ (here $\bar x$ denotes the residue class of $x$ modulo the ideal $(x^2-x)$), so $4\bar x^2-4\bar x=0$. From this we get $(2\bar x-1)^2=1$, so $2\bar x-1$ is invertible.

Comment: @user26857 thank you for the detailed steps, I finally got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb C_U=\mathbb C^{\times}\simeq(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z,+)\times(\mathbb R_{> 0},\cdot)$ by using the isomorphism you suggested. Moreover, $(\mathbb R_{>0},\cdot)\simeq(\mathbb R,+)$ by using logarithm.

$\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2-x)\simeq\mathbb Z[x]/(x-1)\times\mathbb Z[x]/(x)$ by [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings). Moreover, $\mathbb Z[x]/(x-1)\simeq\mathbb Z[x]/(x)\simeq\mathbb Z$, so $(\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2-x))_U\simeq\mathbb Z_U\times\mathbb Z_U$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure if I really understood it. My problem was, that the 0 can't be uniquely represented in polar representation (as far as I understand). So how can this be solved, and how do I use $(\mathbb R_{>0},\cdot)\simeq(\mathbb R,+)$ in this context?

Comment: for the second part: how do you conclude $(\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^2-x))_U\simeq\mathbb Z_U\times\mathbb Z_U$ from your calculations before?

Comment: $0$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb C_U$, so why do you worry about this?

Comment: It's easy to prove that $(A\times B)_U=A_U\times B_U$ for any two rings $A,B$.

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you!